# How to switch to a service user when using Spring Oauth2RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, oauth2resttemplate

I am trying to use Spring's Oauth2RestTemplate, but we need it to use some super user when making a Rest call (we have the user defined), rather than it passing through the user that originally made the service call.

So here's the situation:

`userA` makes a call to `endpointA`.  Naturally, he has permission to hit this endpoint (based on permitted actions in his assigned roles in Keycloak).  `endpointA` will then make a Rest call using the OAuth2RestTemplate to another service, `endpointB`.  However, `userA` does not have permission to hit that endpoint.  This call should be made as a `service-user`, who in our keycloak, is essentially a super user that can do anything.  The problem is, the OAuth2RestTemplate is keeping the same user that made the original call (`userA`) - since he is not permitted to access that endpoint, the call fails (based on RBAC stuff we have set up, separate from the Oauth2 security side of things).

Is there a way to hit an endpoint using `userA`, who has limited access, and have it trigger making a REST call through the OAuth2RestTemplate using a `service-user` that has access to everything? Note: the OAuth2 info for that `service-user` should still be retrieved the same as it would be as if it were still `userA` (lookup in keycloak).  Essentially, this would just be us changing the username before making the REST call (well... I think that's what it entails).

Note: I found a way to temporarily get passed this.  That is by creating a new thread before making the REST call.  This works because Spring no longer has access to the user's security context in that new thread, forcing it to retrieve a new token using the security details provided when creating the OAuth2RestTemplate.  This shows that another solution (and actually preferred) would be to force the OAuth2RestTemplate to always retrieve a new token when hit (using the ResourceDetails, not a "refresh" of the user's token), rather than using the one stored in the SecurityContextHolder at the start of the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just clearing the context before making the REST call:

```
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()
```

When the OAuth2RestTemplate goes to make the call, it will check to see if Authentication has been done through that holder.  If it does not see a token (which is the case when you clear the context), it will look up a new token using the OAuth2 configuration defined in the ResourceDetails.  Just make sure that it references a client that has the permissions required.